# How to integrate two modules in odoo

Tags: odoo

As delivery button shows on sales page when delivery module is installed.
How can i show that module's button in my custom module.

in this image

[image]the sales, subscriptions etc is showing

Comment: You want to show custom button which you created in sales page after installation of  your custom module ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the sale order view by inheritance.

You can show an example here (sale_stock module) : https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale_stock/views/sale_order_views.xml

Documentaton of the view inheritance : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/views.html#inheritance